# Recording IP Addresses for Adwords

Tags: ip-address, record, google-ads-api

I'm looking at writing some code on my server to record the number of clicks for different IP addresses to detect if any of my competitors are clicking my advert periodically.

What is the best approach...I want to somehow record the IP address everytime someone visits my site from google sponsored link.

My first approach was to record every visit with "gclid" in the URL. However, if the user refreshes the page then I will get a duplicate.

If I do it on session creating then I will miss subsequent clicks.

Is there a way I can distinguish between the first visit from google and subsequent refreshes?

Answer (score 0):

You can store location.href in a cookie and check whether the latest cookie is the current page location.href.

This would cover a few cases beyond simply refreshing the page, but that may suffice for your purposes.